# Delete file on URL in java

Tags: file-io

I want to delete a file which is present on URL given.

For example, URL may look like this - http://localhost:8080/myapp/dir1/test.txt

Is there any way that I can get the complete(real) path of the URL like c:/server/webapps/myapp/dir1/test.txt

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you delete it with java code? you can't do that via browser

```
 try{
        File file = new File("/FilePath/filename.ext");
        if(file.delete()){
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the same as you did, but is not working. The file is not deleting.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. This is my method. private boolean deleteDoc(String strfile) {
  try {
   URL url = new URL(strfile);
   File docfile = new File(url.getFile());
   if (docfile.exists()) {
    boolean test = docfile.delete();
    return test;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return false;
  }
 }

Comment: you will have to pass the PROJECT PATH/app/filename..just get the name of the file and append the project path and directory path to it and then pass it for deletion

Answer (score 0):

Given only a URL such as  http://localhost:8080/myapp/dir1/test.txt you cannot reliably determine if and where the file really exists. The Web server (or your application) may even emulate the file programmatically, so that it physically doesn't exist. 
If it is a servlet, it may also implement HTTP DELETE method, so that you can call

```
DELETE /myapp/dir1/test.txt
```

to say the application to delete the file.